# Stopping IIS Application Pool c#

Tags: c#, iis, wmi

I am trying to stop a remote system's IIS application pool using the following c# code:

```
try
{
    // Assign a variable to store the Connection Options
    var connection = new ConnectionOptions();

    // Connect as this user
    connection.Username = Globals.AdminUsername;

    // Connect with this password
    connection.Password = Globals.AdminPassword;

    // Connect using this domain
    connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:MyDomain";

    // Gets or sets a value indicating whether user privileges 
    // need to be enabled for the connection operation.
    connection.EnablePrivileges = true;

    // Enable impersonation so non admins can run admin level commands 
    connection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

    //Each data packet is signed and encrypted. This helps protect 
    // the entire communication between the client and server.
    connection.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;

    // Define a WMI management scope 
    var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\MicrosoftIISv2", ServerName), connection);

    string objPath = "IISApplicationPool.Name='W3SVC/AppPools/" + AppPoolName + "'";

    // Run the query using the scope defined above
    using (ManagementObject AppPool = new ManagementObject(wmiScope,new ManagementPath(objPath), null))
    {
        switch (Action)
        {
            case "Start":
                AppPool.InvokeMethod("Start", null, null);
                break;
            case "Stop":
                AppPool.InvokeMethod("Stop", null, null);
                break;
            case "Recycle":
                AppPool.InvokeMethod("Recycle", null, null);
                break;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

If I stop my application pool it works, but I get a bunch of errors on the server:

```
 -----
 The root\MicrosoftIISv2 namespace is marked with the RequiresEncryption flag. 
 Access to this namespace might be denied if the script or application does not have the 
 appropriate authentication level. Change the authentication level to Pkt_Privacy 
 and run the script or application again.
 -----

 -----
 An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
 Application ID: DefaultDomain
 Process ID: 1640
 Exception: System.AppDomainUnloadedException
 Message: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
 StackTrace: 
 -----

 -----
 Application: w3wp.exe
 Framework Version: v4.0.30319
 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
 Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
 Stack:
 at System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(System.String, System.Type, System.String)
 -----

 -----
 Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x53159a86
 Exception code: 0xe0434352
 Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
 Faulting process id: 0x668
 Faulting application start time: 0x01d194020cab3c08
 Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
 Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
 Report Id: 57bb8e2a-fff5-11e5-8ddc-005056a330b1
 -----
```

I'm pretty sure that I shouldn't be getting these errors because if I manually (vs programmatically) start/stop the application pool I don't get these warnings or errors.

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting these errors. I am setting Packet_Privacy I think so that warning doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks
Brad

Comment: I should note that this only seems to happen on Windows 2008 R2/IIS7. The same code works fine against Windows 2012 R2/IIS 8.1.

Comment: Possibly related: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2932198. Seems there's issues with the ManagementPath class doing stuff which doesn't get cleaned up properly